# How to get an NSDocument subclass to print custom views

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, printing

What needs to be hooked up for an NSDocument subclass to call its print methods when File->Print... is chosen?

How does the File->Print menu get hooked up? (Right now the selector/action is hooked up to first responder's print method. That's in a storyboard, while my NSDocument subclass has its own xib.)

I've tried implementing all of:

```
-(void)print:(id)sender;
-(void)printDocument:(id)sender;
-(void)printDocumentWithSettings:(NSDictionary *)printSettings showPrintPanel:(BOOL)showPrintPanel delegate:(id)delegate didPrintSelector:(SEL)didPrintSelector contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo;
-(NSPrintOperation*)printOperationWithSettings:(NSDictionary *)printSettings error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)outError;
```

But none of them are ever called when I choose Print. Where are these methods supposed to go/who calls them? (I also tried a basic app with a custom view and didn't have luck there either.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay. Looks like the problem is due to a [bug in Xcode](http://openradar.appspot.com/19494505): When creating a Document based app using storyboards the file menu is by default hooked to `print:` and `printDocument:` is not available.

The strange part is that my `print:` call is getting hijacked somewhere along the line but I can't figure out where (at the application level, not the document, because the print dialog is a window not a sheet). `printDocument:` works as expected, but must be defined manually in order to hook it up.

This is for a document-based app, targeting 10.10, and using storyboards.

In the storyboard with Main Menu, add a User Defined Action for `printDocument:` (This is where storyboard based differs, and I feel is a bug. Xib based do not require this User Defined Action.)

[image: Attributes Inspector for First Responder]

Hook up the selector for File -> Print to First Responder and choose `printDocument:` instead of `print:`

Don't define `printDocument:` in your NSDocument subclass. If you want to, then be sure to call `super` or perhaps one of the methods below.

From NSDocument.h

```
/* The action of the File menu's Print... item in a document-based application.
The default implementation of this method merely invokes
[self printDocumentWithSettings:[NSDictionary dictionary]
  showPrintPanel:YES 
        delegate:nil
didPrintSelector:NULL
     contextInfo:NULL].
*/
- (IBAction)printDocument:(id)sender;
```

The default implementation of `printDocumentWithSettings` in turn calls `printOperationWithSettings`, so you can use either of those methods to draw custom information prior to the print sheet appearing.

Comment: Non-storyboard document-based applications start with Print pointing at printDocument, but if you remove the connection and try to put it back you must add it manually as above, so maybe the bug is more general, or I'm missing a setting somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted solution of setting the menu item to `-printDocument:` is correct, but not (technically) because of an Xcode bug.  (It is very a poor default setting, though.)

The menu item is calling the `-print:` of the whatever is the first-responder.  NSView implements `-print:`, so if anything has been set as first-responder you will print with NSView's `-print:`, not your document's `-print:`.  If editing your document requires text editing, the control you are using to implement editing will be set to first-responder, and that control will get the `-print:`.

Comment: Very helpful. There is no need for owenfi's elaborate workaround; it is sufficient to repoint the Print menu item's action to `printDocument:` (already present in the First Responder's list of possible received actions) and implement `printDocument:`. The nil-targeted action will thus arrive up the responder chain in good order.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the TextEdit sample code from Apple (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/TextEdit/Introduction/Intro.html)

In my non-document based app I have set a custom action for the print menu item. In that method I notified my controller about the print operation via `NSNotificationCenter`. Maybe that works for you too :)

Comment: From that example, the File->Print menu is hooked up to First Responder's "printDocument:" which I can't find anywhere else in the source (not even the User Defined First Responder actions - though grep shows it is in something called designable.nib, exposed nowhere in Xcode I can see). That method isn't available on First Responder in my apps (either the document based one, or the standard one) but does look crucial to getting the printOperationWithSettings: method to be called. (If I change from printDocument: to print: in textedit, it no longer prints.)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me root cause it to a perceived Xcode bug.